# how to make color for a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ansi-colors

How to make color for a string in Ruby? For example, define a method make_color,

```
def make_color(str, :red)
end
```

Then the output will return the String str with red color.

I wonder whether there is a lib in ruby can help me do that?

ps: I prefer not using gem package.

Comment: Is this in the terminal?

Comment: @Linuxios, Yes, I will output the string in a UNIX/LINUX box terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [colorize](http://colorize.rubyforge.org/files/README_txt.html) gem

Install the gem and you can use `colorize` method to specify the color you want

```
require 'colorize'
puts "This is blue".colorize( :blue )
```

Or you can simply use the codes as you would in bash

for eg:

```
def make_color(str, color)
  colors = {:red => 31, :green => 32, :blue => 34}
  puts "\e[#{colors[color]}m #{str}\e[0m"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Vimsha, but what if we don't use gem?

Comment: nice job! That's my need.